# only change css file of yii widget, where to save this file

Tags: yii, widget

I want to make changes to a css file of a widget (Yii). Where do I have to put only the changed css if i do not want to change the core files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok....

example CGridView widget:

define id for above widget then (example: #id=gridID)

now
 your css file: #gridID.grid-view `{ property: change}`